# Game Screeps - creep.room.find(Game.CONSTRUCTION_SITES); not working

Tags: javascript, screeps

I have the following code from the tutorial, except in simulation mode it isn't working..

```
if(creep.memory.role == 'builder') {

    if(creep.energy === 0) {
        creep.moveTo(Game.spawns.Spawn1);
        Game.spawns.Spawn1.transferEnergy(creep);
    }
    else {
        var targets = creep.room.find(Game.CONSTRUCTION_SITES);
        if(targets.length) {
            creep.moveTo(targets[0]);
            creep.build(targets[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Printing the result of "targets" in the console, responds undefined.
Can anyone explain how the "CONSTRUCTION_SITES" constant is working and how to find them inside the room?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code looks right to me, it seems that you don't actually have any constructions set for the builders to build. Did you use the "Construct" menu on the left to build a road, for example?

Comment: Thanks for you're quick reply. Solved my problem indeed. Did not know I had to use the Construct menu. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'm quite stoked about screeps, can't wait for the full game release :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this has been answered yet, or if it's just that the syntax from the game has changed which is why you initially wrote it this way, but this code works for what you're doing:

```
var targets = creep.room.find(FIND_CONSTRUCTION_SITES);
```

Answer (score -2):

In Screeps `console.log()` always prints undefined. In line before undefined you can find printed value:

```
> console.log(Game)
[hh:mm:ss] [object Object]
< undefined
```

Comment: When using console.log() inside the script editor instead of the console i won't print undefined if a value can be printed.